is it ok to ask job market question here?
I notice lot of question were asked about stochastic process, option pricing, but much less question about empirical asset pricing, Eugene Fama and Robert Shiller's stuff.
I thought empirical asset pricing is more popular in job market. And there just much less opportunities to do risk neutral pricing thing. And I would think more question would be asked about empirical finance or financial econometric. but looks like the opposite.

I think those are on-topic, I actually have asked some questions on those topics myself. So please ask and answer away.
If for some reason that somehow gives unwanted results we can evaluate but I certainly hope that won't be the case.
